# pixelated render

Tags: rendering

[image][image]I am a new-ish blender user and I have so much trouble with rendering. I feel like no matter how many videos I watch my renders always come out blurry. Can anyone help me maybe clear up stuff I'm missing or don't understand? ... Thanks[image]

Comment: Do you have motion blur enabled intentionally?

Comment: @if u r new and rnt doing any complex renders then u wanna disable motion blur

Comment: I just watched a tutorial about making renders more clear and they said to turn it on, but i just turned it off and it's still blurry if you zoom in

Comment: Could you add a picture of your resolution settings and an example of your blurry render? It would really help us evaluate the problem better.

Comment: Ok I added them up there! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You should not set the render resolution percentage to 200%

Comment: Additionally, how do you mean blurry?